# Rails: How to write model spec for this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I've just started to take on my first `model spec` task at work. After writing a lot of feature specs, I find it hard to get into the different perspective of writing model specs (not taking the context into consideration). I'll take a method of the `Order` model as an example, to explain which difficulties I am experiencing:

```
def update_order_prices
  self.shipping_price_cents = SHIPPING_PRICE_CENTS unless shipping_price_cents

  return if order_lines.empty?

  self.total_price_cents = calculate_order_price
  self.total_line_items_price_cents = calculate_total_order_line_price
  self.total_tax_cents = calculate_tax_amount
end
```

**EDIT TL;DR**

I am totally happy with an answer that simply writes me a spec for this method. The rest of the post just shows what I tried so far but is not necessary to answer this question.

**First approach:**

At first I didn't know what to test for. I tried to find out when and where the method was called and to find a scenario where I would know what the attributes that are touched in this method should be equal to. Put short, I spent a lot of time trying to understand the context. Then a coworker said that I should test methods in model specs self-contained, independent from the context. I should just make sure I identify all cases. So for this method that would be:

- it sets shipping price cents to default (if not done already)
- it returns early if order_lines is empty
- it sets values if order_line is set

**Current approach:**

I tried writing the tests for these points but still questions arise:

**Test 1**

```
it 'sets shipping price cents to default (if not done already)' do
  order.shipping_price_cents = nil
  order.update_order_prices

  expect(order.shipping_price_cents).to eq(Order::SHIPPING_PRICE_CENTS)
end
```

I am confident I got this one right, but feel free to prove me wrong. I set shipping_price_cents to nil to trigger the code that sets it, call the tested method on the cents to be equal to the default value as defined in the model.

**Test 2**

```
it 'returns early if order_lines is empty' do
  expect(order.update_order_prices).to eq(nil)
end
```

So here I want to test that the method returns early when there is no object in the `order_lines` association. I didn't have a clue how to do that so I went into the console, took an order, removed the order_lines associated with it, and called the method to see what would be returned.

```
2.3.1 :011 > o.order_lines
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
2.3.1 :012 > o.update_order_prices
=> nil
```

Then did the same for an order with associated order_line:

```
2.3.1 :017 > o.update_order_prices
=> 1661
```

So I tested for 'nil' to be returned. But it doesn't feel like I am testing the right thing.

**Test 3**

```
it 'sets (the correct?) values if order_line is set' do

  order_line = create(:order_line, product: product)
  order = create(:order, order_lines: [order_line])
  order.update_order_prices

  expect(order.total_price_cents).to eq(order.calculate_order_price)
  expect(order.total_line_items_price_cents).to eq(order.calculate_order_line_price)
  expect(order.total_tax_cents).to eq(order.calculate_tax_amount)
end
```

I simply test that the attributes equal what they are set to, without using actual values, as I shouldn't look outside. If I wanted to test for an absolute value, I would have to investigate outside of this function which then wouldn't test the method but also status of the Order object etc.?

**Running the tests**

```
Failures:
1) Order Methods: #update_order_prices sets (the correct?) values if order_line is set
 Failure/Error: expect(order.total_price_cents).to eq(order.calculate_order_price)

 NoMethodError:
   private method `calculate_order_price' called for #<Order:0x007ff9ee643df0>
   Did you mean?  update_order_prices
```

So, the first two tests passed, the third one didn't. At this point I feel a bit lost and would love hear how some experienced developers would write this seemingly simple test.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to spec against the exact values you are expecting after `update_order_prices`.

Let's say you set up your order and order lines to have a total price of 10 euros then I'd add the following expectation

`expect(order.total_price_cents).to eq(1000)`

Same for the other methods. Generally I try to test against specific values. Also as you are relying on the result of a private method you only care about the result.

Comment: Am I not testing the state of the app then?

Comment: no, you just want to spec the correct result of the methods called with the preconditions you defined before. This means that in your app a product which may be associated with an order line costs 100 euros but in your (model/unit) spec you just set 1 euro and verify that the result is what you expect. state would be tested with integration specs.